# Как вставить картинку-подложку для текста посредством jquery?

Tags: jquery, text

Нужно добавить подложку-картинку для текста. Текст заключен в блоки. Получается так:

```
( 1блок текста) блок <div><p>text</p></div>,
(2 блок текста) <div><p>text</p></div>, (3 блок текста) <div><p>text</p></div>.
```

Нужно добавить одну и ту же подложку для всех блоков с текстом, при том в свойствах jquery указать padding. Как?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
  jQuery("div").css("background-image","url('https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a8f23929c678fe61e9837f7c29f0b9e8?s=48&d=identicon')");
  jQuery("div").css("padding","10px");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div><p>text</p></div>
<div><p>text</p></div>
<div><p>text</p></div>
</body>
```